# Facebook App Center Review

Tags: android, facebook

I created a small Android application for uploading images into a selected Facebook Album. For development I am using the official Facebook SDK for Android.

Next I updated my application details at Facebook and submitted these details to the Facebook App Center Review so that my application could be listed in the Facebook App Overview.

From review team I got the following feedback

*General Feedback:
Your Android app must use the native Login dialog that comes with Facebook's SDKs instead of custom web views. Ensure you have successfully tested your Facebook Login integration for Single Sign On or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more details here*

So I am using the native Login Dialog and SSO works as well.

Do I have any possibility to get in contact with the Review Team that they can tell me exactly what is missing? Or does someone know how to fix this issue?

I already submitted again with the hint that I am using the native login dialog but I only got the same feedback back again without any additional informations.

Regards

Michael

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: not really. I uploaded a new version of my app to play store and resubmitted to the App Center Review and two day laters my application were live. So I never got an answer whats wrong or right

Answer (score 1):

The image on the right is a custom web view. Please make sure that the login screen is not modified like the example on the left.

[image]

Hope this helps! =]